How to query a machine with multimonitors and display Resolution and refresh rate
The machines I am scanning have 2-3 monitors.
This command does almost everything that I need.
Get-CimInstance WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi

However my report needs to include resolution and refresh rate of the monitors.
I had actually figured this out before but can't remember how I did it.
I am specifically looking these properties OF EACH MONITOR:

HorizontalResolution
VerticalResolution
MaxRefreshRate
RefreshRate

I believe I used:
Get-WMiObject
or
get-ciminstance

and then somehow used
CIM_MonitorResolution 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-monitorresolution)

I also tried:
For ciminstace I used:
get-ciminstance -classname CIM_MonitorResolution
get-ciminstance -classname CIM_MonitorResolution -Namespace "root\cimv2"

These never errored out but they also don't display anything.
This got me close:
Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root\cimv2" -ClassName "CIM_VideoControllerResolution"

but it displays every single resolution and refresh that your monitors can use but it doesn't say what monitor.
Does anyone know how I would get those properties for the monitors using powershell without any 3rd party utilities like from Nirsoft.
I am specifically looking these properties OF EACH MONITOR:
HorizontalResolution;
VerticalResolution;
MaxRefreshRate;
RefreshRate; 


Get-DisplayResolution  (see: https://superuser.com/a/1718068/421114 ). for multi-monitor see: Use PowerShell to Discover Multi-Monitor Information)

@luuk - I appreciate your answer. None of the items provided work. I had seen all the links in your answer and none of them work. Get-DisplayResolution is good for only the primary screen and has no way of selecting othe monitors. The link about multi-monitor info is really only good if you have a monitor in two different cards. It shows your the primary monitor on each card. I have typically only one video card with 2 or 3 monitors that I would like to create a report on. I am just not sure how I can call "CIM_MonitorResolution" to get this info.

Perhaps this post helps, but it's not for the faint of heart.

This: C# - How to get real screen resolution in multiple monitors context?, should also be retrievable via PowerShell: powershell -Command "[System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens | ft Bounds"   (sorry cannot test, I only have 1 monitor attached)

@Luuk, Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms; ([System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens).Bounds offers a partial solution; it won't give you refresh-rate info. The post I linked to in my previous comment uses [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens as a starting point to find more detailed device information, albeit via low-level APIs.

My module DisplayConfig can get the resolution and refresh rate info with Get-DisplayInfo. I don't currently have a way to get the max refresh rate, but you can get it in a hacky way through tab completion (TabExpansion2 'Set-DisplayRefreshRate -DisplayId 1 -RefreshRate:').CompletionMatches.CompletionText | sort {[double]$_} -Descending | select -First 1
Here's a full example:
Get-DisplayInfo | Where-Object -Property Active -EQ $true | ForEach-Object -Process {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        DisplayId      = $_.DisplayId
        DisplayName    = $_.DisplayName
        Width          = $_.Mode.Width
        Height         = $_.Mode.Height
        RefreshRate    = $_.Mode.RefreshRate
        MaxRefreshRate = (TabExpansion2 "Set-DisplayRefreshRate -DisplayId $($_.DisplayId) -RefreshRate:").CompletionMatches.CompletionText | sort {[double]$_} -Descending | select -First 1
    }
}

It should be noted that this doesn't take the current resolution into account which can lead to misleading results. For example your display may support 120 Hz but only at 1080p without HDR enabled so if you are at 4K you won't actually be able to use the listed refresh rate.
